# Create SQL Server Database from Excel Table

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I currently have a report in Excel based off a database which contains the following columns:

`Table Name, Column Name, Data Type, Max Length, Precision, Scale`

I would like to know if I can import this into another copy of SQL Server to recreate the empty database. I currently have no access to the source database and so need to go from this meta data.

Comment: You could have a look at generating databases with Biml and BimlScript. http://agilebi.com/jwelch/2011/05/26/creating-tables-using-biml-and-bimlscript/

Comment: You could do it with a script task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses - my approach was to concatenate up a create statement in Excel which could then be copied and pasted into SQL Server.

So

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
column_name1 data_type(size),
column_name2 data_type(size),
column_name3 data_type(size),
....
);
```

Was formed into

```
"CREATE TABLE" & table_name"&
    "("&
    column_name1 &" "& data_type &"("& size &"),"&
    ....
```

and run down my list of fields.

Took around 5 minutes to enter in a few hundred tables into SQL from the report.